# Search value in large table using C# (Dictionary with multiple keys)

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, large-data, multikey

I have a table in RAM (from DB + file) with 20+ fields and 100K+ rows. So i need search rows by 6 differents fields. What the best structure for this task in C#?

- Using List is bad because searching too long.
- Using external software (as elastic search) is not good because task used once per day, and no other reason to use external hard software
- Using 6 tuples is possible but not nice solution

I used 6 Dictionary and can merged it in one custom class, but may be .net has another structure (builded or nuget) about i dont know

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is probably to use the database instead of reinventing the wheel. Databases may run completely in memory, or efficiently cache tables in memory for fast queries. Some databases can also run in process. See for example [SQLite in memory](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html). Make sure to have indices for the columns used for searching. Replicating the same functionality is probably not worth the effort unless you have some very special requirements that are difficult to implement with a database.

If you insist on writing this yourself the simplest option is probably to just use multiple dictionaries. To avoid storing multiple copies of a row you can use dictionaries that map a key to a index in a common list used by all dictionaries. Note that regular dictionaries cannot store multiple values for the same key, see [MultiValueDictionary](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/archive/src/Microsoft.Experimental.Collections/Microsoft/Collections/Extensions/MultiValueDictionary.cs) if that is needed.

Comment: Thank you for answer!
DB server cant use because it busy, but app server has RAM that i can use free. So DB in not solution in current situation.
Multeple dictionaries i use now, but may be another structure instead of many dicts? I see that many people has same problems and, as i see, every use self created solutions.

Comment: @RenatNusratullin I'm no DB expert, but dismissing using a DB because it is "busy" is probably not wise. Perhaps *it* needs more memory? Or CPU? or is it busy because it lacks indices and runs full table scans? Or some are other optimizations needed? Database management and optimization is a science into itself.